# Ring contained in a R-module finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain with quotient field $K$ and let $b_1,\ldots,b_n\in K$.

Suppose that $R'$ is a  integral domain, $R\subseteq R'$ and

$$R'\subseteq \sum_j Rb_j.$$

**Remark:** It is well know that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module then $M$ is Noetherian.

Thus, the  $R$-module $\sum_j Rb_j$ is   Noetherian.

Now, let $I$ be a ideal of $R'$, then $I$ is a $R$-submodule of $\sum_j Rb_j.$

This implies that $I$ is  a finitely generated   $R$-submodule, in particular is finitely generated as $R'$-module.

The conclusion is that $R'$ is a Noetherian ring.

Is correct  ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Why are you saying  "Now, let $I$ be a ideal of $R'$, then $I$ is a $R$-submodule of $\sum_j Rb_j.$" It will be $R'$ submodule, I agree, but I do not think it has to $R$ module.

Comment: Because $R\subseteq R'$, then $I$ is a $R-$ submodule of $\sum_j Rb_j.$. right?

Comment: Ohh ya. Ok. But from here we can only say that $I$ is a noetherian module over $R$.  Not that $R'$ is noetherian. Why you concluded this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor remark: you should assume that $R'$ is a subring of $K$, containing $R$. This ensures the operations match.

Your proof is correct. Here's how it can be generalized.

First of all, $R'$ is an $R$-algebra, in particular an $R$-module. Since $R'$ is contained in a finitely generated $R$-module, it is noetherian as an $R$-module.

Now we prove that whenever $A$ is an $R$-algebra, finitely generated as $R$-module, it is a noetherian ring. (Of course, we keep the basic hypothesis that $R$ is a noetherian ring).

If $I_0\subseteq I_1\subseteq\dots\subseteq I_n\subseteq \dotsb$ is an ascending chain of ideals of $A$, it is also an ascending chain of $R$-submodules of $A$, so it stabilizes.